# Edit csv column

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv with 3 columns.

```
Date    Time    Event
12/19/2021  3:00pm  Low
12/19/2021  1:30pm  Low
12/20/2021  3:00pm  Low
```

I'm trying to subtract 5 hours from each row.
How can I keep each object in a `datetime` format?

```
$time0 = Import-Csv $Tempdest | Select 'Time'

$timeEst = $time0 | ForEach-Object {
Write-Host $_.
            ([datetime]$_).AddHours(-5)
}
```

Comment: Please, share the Csv as plain text instead of screenshot

Comment: Updated Question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the provided screenshot this should work, it would be updating the imported CSV in memory. If it doesn't work it's best if you can share with us the CSV as plain text.

```
$csv = Import-Csv path/to/csv.csv

$csv | ForEach-Object {
    $date = '{0} {1}' -f $_.Date, $_.Time -as [datetime]
    $date = $date.AddHours(-5)
    $_.Date = $date.ToShortDateString()
    $_.Time = $date.ToShortTimeString()
}

$csv | Format-Table
```

Comment: That is fantatsic!  Thank you Santiago.
What does $date = '{0} {1}' mean?

Comment: @MattyS happy to help :). That is known as [_string formatting_](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-powershell-and-basic-string-formatting/) or [`String.Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Is it still possible to manipulate the Time?
For example.. If I were to create another column and have each line value be 15 minutes early (addminutes -15)?

Comment: @MattyS yeah it is, you would just need more manipulation of the columns to get back a `datetime` object. it would look something like `'{0} {1}:{2}' -f $_.Date, $_.Hour, $_.Minutes`

Comment: I can start another question. @Santiago

Comment: @MattyS sure, If I see it i'll help you. Remember to add your CSV to the question as plain text